# Drupal Services RestApi Login

Tags: php, rest, drupal, drupal-7

I made a successful login to remote drupal site ... but after that I'm not able to redirect to that site as a logged in user.
This is my code for login:

```
<?php
function sso_login(){
$base_url = 'http://localhost_site_url/user_operation';
 $data = array(
  'username' => 'admin',
  'password' => 'admin',
);
$data = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
$options = array(
  'headers' => array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
  ),
  'method' => 'POST',
  'data' => $data,
  'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
);


$response = drupal_http_request($base_url . '/user/login', $options);
$data = json_decode($response->data);


// Check if login was successful
if ($response->code == 200) {
$options['headers']['Cookie'] = $data->session_name . '=' . $data->sessid;


// Get info about a user 
    $data = array();
    $options['data'] = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
    $options['method'] = 'GET';
    $response = drupal_http_request($base_url . '/user/1', $options);
}
?>
```

So... if the response is 200 - the user is logged in .. how can I after that redirects user to the remote site as a logged in user??? I suppose that the session cookie should be sent somehow...but I'm not sure how!!!

Could anyone help.